# Azure APIM - How can I Request/POST. I want to block certain characters and allow few?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

Azure APIM - How can I Request/POST. I want to block certain characters and allow few in incoming POST?

```
<set-body>@(context.Request.Body.As<string>(preserveContent: true))</set-body>
```

I have above line in my Policy and need to Parse it / Iterate through to only allow 's and block all other (') combinations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use multiline syntax for more complex logic:

```
<set-body>@{
    var body = context.Request.Body.As<string>(preserveContent: true);
    body = body.Replace("'", string.Empty);
    return body;
}</set-body>
```

But if it's just replacement you need to do look into our find-and-replace policy - it's more efficient that sample above.